# I am looking for some sample code for SOAP messaging for my Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am a beginner in web services and I want to use soap messaging for a web service. My web service is working fine, and I want all the communication with the client to use SOAP messages. Searching in google, i couldn't find some good sample code for what I want. Both service and client are in Java. I have some web methods like the following.

```
public SomethingDTO getSomethingById(Long id) {
    try {
        InitialContext ctx2 = new InitialContext();
        UserTransaction utx = (UserTransaction) ctx2.lookup("java:module/UserTransaction");
        utx.begin();

        SomethingDTO something = null;
        if (id != null) {
            SomethingDAO somethingDAO = new SomethingDAO();
            something = somethingDAO.findById(id, false);
            if (something == null) {
                System.out.println("No data found");
            }
        }
        utx.commit();
        return something;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And I want to add soap messaging.

Comment: Please explain your question in brief, add some sample code or examples

Comment: I added some code. I don't know if this helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to understand and help you. 
When you deploy the web service the SOAP message will look like.

`

```
<definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.intech.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://ws.intech.com/" name="HelloWorldImplService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://ws.intech.com/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="getSomethingById">
<part name="arg0" type="xsd:long"/>
</message>
<message name="getSomethingByIdResponse">
<part name="return" type="tns:somethingDTO"/>
</message>
<portType name="HelloWorld">
<operation name="getSomethingById">
<input message="tns:getSomethingById"/>
<output message="tns:getSomethingByIdResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="HelloWorldImplPortBinding" type="tns:HelloWorld">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
<operation name="getSomethingById">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://ws.intech.com/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://ws.intech.com/"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="HelloWorldImplService">
<port name="HelloWorldImplPort" binding="tns:HelloWorldImplPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:9999/ws/hello"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

`
Hope I am correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What i want more, is what lines i have to add in my web service method, so that soap messaging begins.